# take 10 records and skip 10 records in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 20 records in my SQL table. I want to take the first 10 records (0-10) for the sender_id then skip and take the last 10 records (10-20) for the receiver_id

```
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'sender_id' => User::limit(10)->inRandomOrder()->get()->first()->id,
            'receiver_id' => User::skip(10)->take(10)->inRandomOrder()->get()->first()->id,
        ];
    }
```

The problem is that even after defining the limit at 10 I still have records with id higher than 10 in the 'sender_id' which is supposed to be (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: no, you are ordering them in random order, then taking 10 ... however the problem you are trying to solve is very unclear... which of those 2 lines has the problem? what is the output? what is the desired output?

Comment: I guess, the ID's higher than 10 are caused by `inRandomOrder()`. Does that still happen if you sort the query by id?

Comment: `->get()->first()` does not work, you have to use either `first()` or `get()`. `first()->id` will fail if there is no `first()`.

Comment: @Tomm can you please add your solution as answer ? thanks

Comment: @Tomm "->get()->first() does not work" - That's not true. Both `Builder` and `Collection` do have a method called `first()`.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden please add your comment as an answer it works for me thanks

Comment: @Tomm since get method returns collection type, first method on the collection type still work. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this method.
random() is a helper function in collection laravel and returns a random item from the collection https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-random

```
User::take(10)->get()->random()->id
User::skip(10)->take(10)->get()->random()->id
```

Comment: Could you please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68472152/edit) [a little more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68472152/edit)?

Comment: random() is a helper function in collection laravel and returns a random item from the collection https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-random

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want the id of one user randomly chosen between the first 10, why not randomly skip some entries and take the first?

E.g.

```php
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'sender_id' => User::skip(rand(0, 9))->first()->id,
            'receiver_id' => User::skip(rand(10, 19))->first()->id,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: In the worst case worst, you end up with `User::skip(10)` for `sender_id` (max value) as well as `User::skip(10)` for `receiver_id` (min value). You probably meant `User::skip(rand(11, 20))` for `receiver_id`, right?

Comment: Indeed, skipping 10 results in the 11th. I've updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a slightly weird definition to distinguish to "models" by their id inside the same table. To make it a bit more logical, I'd go with [scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes):

```
class User extends Model {
    public function scopeSender($query)
    {
        return $query->whereBetween('id', [ 1, 10 ]);
    }

    public function scopeReceiver($query)
    {
        return $query->whereBetween('id', [ 11, 20 ]);
    }
}
```

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'sender_id' => User::sender()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
            'receiver_id' => User::receiver()->inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
        ];
    }
```